# Using Query to ignore covid return 0 results in newsapi

Tags: html

I am trying to ignore news from covid while querying news from newapi.org. And when I use the command to ignore a word "&q=-covid" I get 0 results. If I query for covid using "&q=covid" I get 2 results. And without any query, I get 38.

So when I ask it to ignore news that has covid in the name I should get 36 results and not 0.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong??

Here is the code:

```
https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY&q=-covid
```

pls get new key from site

try removing "&q=-covid" or replacing the - with + to get full entries and entries with covid in the name.

Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: Do they not have support?

Comment: @epascarello They have a contact email address and a Twitter handle. I have messaged them on twitter.

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is add the query terms *before* the API key itself. Simply adjusting the placement of your `q=-covid` to the beginning of the query will do the trick.

So instead try this, here: `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=-covid&apiKey=660fe4700bd34641aa93bcc5b3ed38ee`

If you're looking to make further adjustments to the cURL, this link to the NewsAPI documentation discusses how to utilize the query structure - which may be helpful: https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything

Comment: Doesn't make any difference if I place the query before the key

Comment: @SiddharthShekar review the provided url to see that the query is executing as requested.

Comment: I get "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost.". But I notice now that you changed it to "Everything" from "Top headlines", which was my question. I assumed it worked on top headlines as well, seems that the q=-query only works on everything.